# Matplotlib legend: how to assign multiple scatterpoints values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, markers

I'm using the matplotlib library in python to generate publication-quality xy scatter plots.  I ran into a problem regarding the markers in the legend. I'm plotting 2 different xy-scatter series; one is a set of xy points that forms a curve, and the other is a single xy point.

I would like the legend to show 3 markers for the "curve", and 1 marker for the single point. The only way I know how to change the number of legend markers is using the "scatterpoints" argument when declaring the legend. However, this argument sets the number of markers for *all* series in the legend, and I'm not sure how to change each legend entry *individually*.

Sadly I can't post pictures as a new user, but hopefully this description is sufficient. **Is there a way to set scatterpoints values individually for each legend entry using matplotlib?**

EDIT: Here are links showing images with different values for scatterpoints.

scatterpoints = 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK4Kn.jpg

scatterpoints = 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAp2G.jpg

Hopefully this makes the issue a bit more clear.

Comment: do you want to split the 'curve' in three 'segments' and use a different marker for each segment? How do you want to assign markers to points of the scatter "curve"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get the line in legend, and change it yourself:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
pl.plot(x, np.sin(x), "-x", label=u"sin")
pl.plot(x, np.random.standard_normal(len(x)), 'o', label=u"rand")
leg = pl.legend(numpoints=3)
l = leg.legendHandles[1]
l._legmarker.set_xdata(l._legmarker.get_xdata()[1:2])
l._legmarker.set_ydata(l._legmarker.get_ydata()[1:2])
##or
#l._legmarker.set_markevery(3)
pl.show()
```

Legend.legendHandles is a list of all the lines in legend, and the _legmarker attribute of the line is the marks.

You can call set_markevery(3) or set_xdata() & set_ydata() to change the number of marks.

[image]

Comment: This answer worked great for me, thank you.  I will add one caveat: the _legmarker attribute exists for Line2D collections generated by pyplot.plot(), but does not exist for RegularPolyCollection collections generated by pyplot.scatter().  This was okay in my case, since I simply converted the single point I needed to plot from plt.scatter() to plt.plot().